# How to pass Binding and RemoteAddress to wcf service method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I am trying to access wcf service in asp.net core 3.1. i have added the wcf service as service reference. I am trying to call he client method which contain parameter System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress, so how to pass this two parameter the end point is https link. also i tried this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-specify-a-client-binding-in-code) but for https its not working

thanks in advance

Comment: Will it work if you use http?

Comment: no http link not found

Comment: Have you successfully generated the proxy class? What is wrong with it?

Comment: proxy class ?? i am not getting . in service refrence i have just added the wcf service usign wsdl link and then try to call

Comment: You can refer to this document for creating WCF clients to call WCF services: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-create-a-wcf-client